# Update checkbox value to database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my database entry with an 1 or 0 depends on it is checked or not.

My current code looks like this (only one checkbox, the others are the same just other name):

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form">
  <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="csgo" value="1"><span class="slider"></span></label> CSGO;
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
 <?php
   $csgoac = isset($_POST["csgo"]) ? $_POST["csgo"] : 0;
   $sql = "UPDATE Users SET csgoactive='".$csgoac."' WHERE ID='1'";
   mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 ?>
</form>
```

I tested it with `echo $csgoac;` (before the query) and the output was `checked = 1` and not `checked = 0`.

With the query now, it is only updating "0" to the database, what I did wrong on there?

Comment: Are you sure your query works? Do you have mysqli exceptions switched on? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the first time the page is rendered, `$csgoac` is 0 because `isset($_POST["csgo"])` is false.

If the checkbox is checked and then the form is submitted, `$csgoac` will be 1.

So the question becomes: What is the result of `mysqli_query($db, $sql);`?

Are you getting/checking all available feedback? If `display_errors` is Off in php.ini, there will not be feedback in the browser, but perhaps an error is in the php errorlog. (For instance, in the snippet, `$db` is not defined, so `mysqli_query($db, $sql);` fails with `Undefined variable: db`.).

If the UPDATE is not successful, `mysqli_query($db, $sql);` will return `FALSE` and [`$db->error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) should tell you what error was encountered.

You could also use [`mysqli_stmt_affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) for additional feedback.

Perhaps add some feedback/error checking to get as much information as possible so you can know what is *really* happening.

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: No, I wasn't asking a question. :D I wanted to inform you and others how to get the errors in mysqli. There's much better way to get them than to check `mysqli_error()`